# asynchronous global index maintenance for drop and truncate partition

Tags: oracle

We have a very large partitioned table that needs to drop partition periodically. The business system needs 7*24 hours of operation.

We use global index.

From the following article, we know that Oracle supports asynchronous index update.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/asynchronous-global-index-maintenance-for-drop-and-truncate-partition-12cr1

But : "The actual index maintenance is performed at a later time"\

Does it affect the normal business when it is actually executed.( Query/Insert/Update/Delete )

Comment: What do you mean by *affect*? The index or index partition needs to be `usable` to be used by the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't, as you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-A22047D9-61D1-4C00-8C1C-0F7E5C7D4F5B.htm#VLDBG1373) (I supposed you are running 12.1 as you didn't specify database version and you linked 12.1 documentation).

The parts that are of interest to you are the following:

> The partitions of tables containing local indexes are locked to prevent DML operations against the affect table partitions, except for an ONLINE MOVE operation. However, unlike the index maintenance for local indexes, **any global index is still fully available for DML operations and does not affect the online availability of the OLTP system**.

[...]

> For example, dropping an old partition is semantically equivalent to deleting all the records of the old partition using the SQL DELETE statement. In the DML case, all index entries of the deleted data set have to be removed from any global index as a standard index maintenance operation, **which does not affect the availability of an index for SELECT and DML operations**.